# Chronology of the Quran

Tags: quran, history

There are several attempts to estimate the chronological order of the Surahs.

Many decisions may have been estimated through analogy between the contents and the traditions on history.

My question is: Are there any ancient sources that claim to or are likely to go back to direct oral traditions?

Side question: Does anyone know a link to a critical apparatus on a more or less recent estimation of the chronology?

Links:
[Order of Egyptian Standard and Nöldecke on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chapters_in_the_Quran)
[Qran.org](http://www.qran.org/q-chrono.htm)
[Edgecomb](https://web.archive.org/web/20180113191410/http://www.bombaxo.com/chronsurs.html)

Related questions on this site:

[Is there a way to reconcile the traditional chronology of early surahs with the biographies of Muhammad?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33640/is-there-a-way-to-reconcile-the-traditional-chronology-of-early-surahs-with-the)

[Are there rulings, apart from alcohol consumption, whose chronology may be found in the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50126/are-there-rulings-apart-from-alcohol-consumption-whose-chronology-may-be-found)

[Is it possible to compile the Quran chronologically, are there books about this?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28856/is-it-possible-to-compile-the-quran-chronologically-are-there-books-about-this)

Comment: You missed to mention [is it possible to compile the qur'an chronologically. Are there books about this?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28856/is-it-possible-to-compile-the-quran-chronologically-are-there-books-about-this) which seems very close to some of your requests.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Indeed, I didn't find it in my search. However, neither the question nor the answer indicate an ancient source. Maybe, there is no such source.